# Need help on slow Ubuntu 16.4 BootUp time

Tags: boot

I am a newbie in Ubuntu and having trouble with my Ubuntu 16.4 booting up on SSD. The total time required to bootup is 3minutes and 7 seconds. I ran `systemd-analyze blame` and here's the result:

[image]

Most of the services does'nt require that much time. I ran another line of code and got this. The boot image I captured that have a large gap in between two system running:

[image]

I appreciates all your help in troubleshooting this !